# Patient No. 141

Tags: mathematics, wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, acrostic

I have a rare disease and it is really dangerous. I need oxygen tanks supplying oxygen to me. It is like I rely on oxygen tanks more than water and food. I think that my path to cure takes wholehearted optimism from my friends and colleagues who have constantly been supporting me and I think that there is a ray of hope far away in the horizon for me.

> Your job is to find the puzzle and give the answer.

> **BONUS**: Also find how the puzzle is related to the title

**HINT 1**

> I have added a tag but that by no means changes the answer.

**HINT 2**

> I have added another tag but that by no means changes the answer.

**HINT 3**

> Look for an operation and a number keeping in mind the tags

**HINT 4**

> I am surprised why no one has been able to solve this puzzle. Now, after adding the  [acrostics](/questions/tagged/acrostics) tag, the answer must be obvious

Comment: haha at first, my idiot brain screamed "It's SCP-141!!) even though I didn't even remember what that one was, but nope. 141 is a book and clearly cannot breathe or anything of the sort. GL everyone on solving this!

Comment: You say that the puzzle is to find the puzzle and give the answer.  So we already know what the puzzle is.  It is: find what the puzzle is and give the answer.  Since the question also answers the question, it is also the answer.  Done.

Comment: @FlorianF Woah, that is a little too much thinking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the words found by @JMP, I'm guessing the answer is

> Root two = $\sqrt{2} \approx 1.41$. This fits with Hint $3$ and with the title. However, I don't see how the words Hard, Not and Faith fit in.

Comment: Relate it with the title

Comment: How is Root 2 a disease?

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer:

> $141$ in roman numerals is $CXLI$, which can be interpreted as $C \times LI$. This is 5100, which is $\overline{V}C$, an abbreviation for [vital capacity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vital_capacity). I'm stuck here, but the bar over V makes me think [Guillain–Barré syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guillain%E2%80%93Barr%C3%A9_syndrome), which uses vital capacity as part of its diagnosis.

Comment: See Hint 3, it will give you a path

Answer (score 3):

Partial:

> I **have a rare disease** and it is really dangerous. I **need oxygen tanks** supplying oxygen to me. It is like I **rely on oxygen tanks** more than water and food. I think that my path to cure **takes wholehearted optimism**  from my friends and colleagues who have constantly been supporting me and I think that there is a ray of hope **far away in the horizon** for me.
>
>  gives HARD NOT ROOT TWO FAITH.

Comment: Partly correct. See hint 3

Comment: The puzzle is not about the disease.

Answer (score 2):

**Partial answer**

The title could refer to

> the unicode character U+0141, a capital L with a **stroke**: Ł. A stroke is a disease that affects blood (and therefore oxygen) supply to some part of the body.

Therefore the puzzle could require

> to count the strokes needed to write the text (or part of it).

After edit of the question:

> 141 rings the bell of the first digits of $\sqrt 2=1.414... $.

Comment: That's not the right approach. Well tried though.

Comment: now the new edit is somewhat right. Move ahead.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is

> the the lung desease COPD. It cound be caused by constantly heavy smoking and it requires oxygen to breath. Maybe caused by somking 141 cigattes per day.

Comment: Unfortunately not the right approach. Try after I add a hint.

Comment: I have added a hint try now.I think now, it has to be evident